# Adding Scaffold Identity to Blazor server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am creating currently a Blazor Server. In the solution there are a few projects: some of them is the Blazor server and the DataAccess project (where is the ApplicationDbContext class).

I have to add a Scaffold Identity to the Blazor server but I found it difficult because I can not select the already existing ApplicationDbContext.
I am using .Net6.
Everytime I try to add Scaffold identity this is the error that I get:

[image: adding Identity to server]

Is there any way to add Identity successfully?
Here is where is the server project:
[image: Server Project path]
Here is where my ApplicationDbContext class is:
[image: ApplicationDbContext path]

The process that I follow is: right click on project -> Add Scaffold Identity -> Add Identity. The following window doesn't contain the ApplicationDbContext class and even if I try to write the path to it its still not possible to create the Identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The process that I follow is: right click on project -> Add Scaffold
> Identity -> Add Identity. The following window doesn't contain the
> ApplicationDbContext class and even if I try to write the path to it
> its still not possible to create the Identity.

Well based on your scenario and description it seems that you are trying to integrate [identity within your blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#project-template) server app and encoutered above error.

I think you can do that in other way. For instance, create a blazor identity app with individual account authentication option and then you can update our existing database context stuff to the newly created project. This way, would reduce the hassle and mistached datacontext class issue as well.

Let's have a look how you can do that.

1. Create Blazor Identity Project With Individual Account:

You can do as following:

[image]

2. Blazor Identity Project Structure:

[image]

2. Execute Migration:

Once you are done with project scaffolding, how you should try addding new user  resgistration. You may encounter following exception. Just clicc on Migration apply button.

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Once you are successfully able to resgister new user, you are good to transfer, your existing project context and other files to newly created proejct. In addition, please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#project-template), if you want to study more.

Comment: well I did created identity project, the migration was successfull. Still I don't know if it was the best way to create an individual database for identity. However I even created a user. But what to do after that exactly? Should I add the BlazorIdentityapp as an existing project to my "original" project?

Comment: Now you should migrate your existing file and library to the new project, not all together, step by step in a chunc then build and run, likewise.